# Python Post Request Issue, given error 500

Tags: python, post

```py
body_1 = {"landowner": "asdf@gmail.com","title": report_name,"content": "asdf","project": projectID, } 
url_1 = 'http://' + IP + ':8005/projects/notifications/'
        response_1 = requests.post(url_1, data=body_1, headers=headers)
```

For this, I am getting an error 500, when above I have used a similar process to post and it has worked.

I even wrote this code in javascript, and that works but the python equivalent does not.

I tried to add console logs, and everything works up until the response, where it says code 500.

I tried to follow along with javascript as well and try and model it after that too, but that did not work either.

Comment: Have you tried to dump request and compare it with one working?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you are not sending the data as JSON encoded data. When sending an array as data with a request use the `json` keyword argument. This means your request will look like;

```
response_1 = requests.post(url_1, json=body_1, headers=headers)
```

In the example above `data=` was changed to `json=`.

By using the json argument the data is encoded to `JSON`, and the `Content-Type` header is set to `application/json`.

Learn more about the `json=` keyword argument in the `requests` [documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

If this doesn't fix your issue please add the error output message for the 500 error code.